# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

version:
firefox : Mozilla Firefox 61.0
geckodriver : geckodriver v0.20.1

I only tried below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

But getting an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1
```

And geckodriver.log:

> 1528101123327 geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
>
> 1528101123336 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:43481
>
> 1528101124336 mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.y93GPXwtXuKC"
>
> Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/username/.Xauthority which is owned by username.)

It's only makes a problem in **root account** , Please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webdriver Exception:Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809135/webdriver-exceptionprocess-unexpectedly-closed-with-status-1)

Comment: This could be related to `Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported. ($XAUTHORITY is /home/keti/.Xauthority which is owned by keti.)
```

...implies you were either trying to invoke *Firefox Browser* as a **root** user or running *Firefox Browser* as **root** in a **non-root session**.

As per [**User's Firefox process runs as root (if root is running Firefox)**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353203#c12) both the cases are not supported and should have been relatively difficult to achieve. But technically it was still possible (as the --new-instance and --no-remote flags are available to control remote control) but X11's permissive security model meant an user should basically treat the user account as if it had passwordless sudo.

There were a couple of issues associated as follows:

- If a user runs Firefox as root but using their own home directory, many things become broken for that user, sometimes permanently.
- [When firefox is running as root, other users on the same display can gain root privileges](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=247412)

With the GA (General Availability) of **Firefox v60.0** *Mozilla Team* decided to [**Disallow Firefox from running as sudo**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323302) as:

- [Use clone() instead of fork() for sandboxed Linux processes and remove SandboxEarlyInit etc.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1401062)
- Earlier running **sudo firefox**, which previously seemed to work but was unsupported, now will fail to load content (tab crash on any page) on most *Linux Distributions* and it will fail to start and print a message as:

  ```
  Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported. ($XAUTHORITY is /home/username/.Xauthority which is owned by username.)
  ```

Comment: Then is it okay if I reinstall previous version of Firefox? I should run Firefox Browser as root(starting root@username in terminal)