# Process unexpectedly closed with status 1

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I am running selenium tests with selenium 3.8.0 and geckodriver 0.19.1. During the run some tests pass fine, while for other tests I get the error:

```
Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

My question: **In which code file is this error thrown?**

I am not asking for a solution of my problem as I doubt anyone can help. All I am asking is the source code which throws the error so I can debug it myself.

Comment: some times, the problem with the environments not by the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webdriver Exception:Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809135/webdriver-exceptionprocess-unexpectedly-closed-with-status-1)