# Error while trying to invoke Firefox using Selenium : Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, google-colaboratory

I am trying to invoke firefox on google colaboratory using selenium :
firefox version = 87
geckodriver version = 0.29.0

and I get this error:

```
<ipython-input-22-66e525eac6d9> in <module>()
     10 ff_options.headless = True
     11 
---> 12 ff = Firefox(options=ff_options)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, firefox_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
    172                 command_executor=executor,
    173                 desired_capabilities=capabilities,
--> 174                 keep_alive=True)
    175 
    176         # Selenium remote

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal
```

**Here is my code :**

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver  import FirefoxOptions#.options import Options

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
from selenium import webdriver  #import Firefox, FirefoxOptions, FirefoxProfile

ff_options = FirefoxOptions()
ff_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
ff_options.headless = True

ff = Firefox(options=ff_options)
```

Is there any solution to my problem? Can you help run this code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webdriver Exception:Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809135/webdriver-exceptionprocess-unexpectedly-closed-with-status-1)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I've tried this solution before but I am already trying to run Firefox in headless.

Comment: So `opts.add_argument("--headless")` does not work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't

Comment: This usually happens when there's a mismatch between your geckodriver and firefox version