# How to run Django selenium test in github actions

Tags: django, selenium-webdriver, github-actions

I have a Django selenium test that runs fine on local machine using Firefox Webdrive.
When I try to run it on github actions I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/Pangea/Pangea/core/tests/test_selenium.py", line 12, in setUpClass
    cls.selenium = WebDriver()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 181, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

The test that I am trying to run is very basic as shown below

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver


class TestLoginWithSelenium(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        cls.selenium.maximize_window()
        cls.username = "xyz"
        cls.password = "mnbvcxza"
        cls.server_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_login(self):
        """
        Test Login for a user
        """
        self.assertTrue(1==1)
```

I am running following commands on Github Actions:

```
pip install selenium
sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver
which geckodriver
geckodriver -V
sudo mv /usr/bin/geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
which geckodriver
```

**Mozilla Firefox 99.0**

**geckodriver 0.30.0**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webdriver Exception:Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809135/webdriver-exceptionprocess-unexpectedly-closed-with-status-1)

Answer (score 0):

[Reference on headless firefox option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47642457/3842788)

Following is the modified code to run headless firefox on github actions

**test.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class TestLoginWithSelenium(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        opts = FirefoxOptions()
        opts.add_argument("--headless")
        cls.selenium = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

        # this will run with head and you can actually see the
        # browser open up in tests
        # cls.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()

        cls.username = "xyz"
        cls.password = "mnbvcxza"

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_login(self):
        """
        Test Login for a user
        """
        self.client.logout()
        self.selenium.get(f"{self.live_server_url}{reverse('login')}")
        username_input = self.selenium.find_element(By.ID, "id_auth-username")
        username_input.send_keys(self.username)
        password_input = self.selenium.find_element(By.ID, "id_auth-password")
        password_input.send_keys(self.password)
        self.selenium.find_element(By.ID, 'idLogin').click()
```

**github actions**

```
pip install selenium
sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver
```