# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Selenium, Twitter Web Crawling Using Python
It runs on the local server without any problems
This error occurs when running on a remote server.
I'm not sure why this problem is happening.
How can we solve this problem?

```
    File "twitter.py", line 435, in <module>
    twitter_walk()
  File "twitter.py", line 31, in twitter_walk
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="./geckodriver",options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal


ubuntu 18.04.5
selenium 3.141.0
Mozilla Firefox 86.0
geckodriver 0.29.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webdriver Exception:Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809135/webdriver-exceptionprocess-unexpectedly-closed-with-status-1)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because you are attempting to run the browser in non-headless mode, but your remote server doesn't have a visual display.

To circumvent this, try running Selenium in headless mode by adding the `--headless` argument to the browser.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

browser.get('https://example.com')
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47642457) has more information.